# Copy rows based on multiple cells values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy rows from a significant amount of worksheets.
I have multiple lines that relate to a certain document, depending on the versions. 
Therefore, some lines have the same reference, same name but a different version/date of creation. I'd like to copy to another sheet (Sheet2 for instance) the latest version of every document.

I've tried so far with a few while loops to check all lines and a if to check the value of the date but I failed to make it work, and I wonder if it's an efficient way of doing it.
Here is a picture of my problem and a part of the code I wrote :

```
Dim Name as String
Dim Dates as Date
With Sheets(Sheet1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Name = Cells(1,3) 'Initialise Name
    Dates = Cells(1,5) 'Initialise Dates
    LineCopy = 1 'The line we'll copy
    Line = 1 'The line we use to check the sheet
    While Name <> "" 'if the name is not empty, ie there are no documents left



        While Sheets(Sheet1).StrComp(Name, .Cells(Line, 3)) = True 'WHile you are working with a same name document
            If .Cells(Line, 5) > Dates Then 'If the document is older, then choose it.
                Dates = .Cells(Line, 5)

            Else
                LineCopy = Line 'If there are no older documents, then it's the one to copy
                Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A" & LineCopy & ":" & "E" & LineCopy).Copy ' Copy the oldest document

                Sheets(Sheet2).Paste
            End If

            Line = Line + 1 ' Increment the Line in the second while to check every line

        Wend
        Name = .Cells(LineCopy + 1, 6) 'After the first while, let's change name to the second document and do it all over again.

    Wend
```

[image: My problem]

Comment: so you want to copy the rows based on latest date with unique reference. am i right?

Comment: as per my understanding you want this function `=MAX(E2:E4)` it gives you the latest date

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how many lines there is for each document.

Comment: you want to do it in multiple workbooks?

Comment: Multiple Sheets on a single book

Comment: can you pls show a sample of your required output

Comment: Line 4 and 6 on my example would be my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need the formating I think copy and paste should be avoided.

The below code assumes the data is sorted on column A. If not another aproach is needed.

Edit: Adapted to comment that there may be blank rows.

```
Dim max_date As Date
Dim max_row As Long
Dim old_sheet As Worksheet
Dim new_sheet As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long
Dim last_name as String

Set new_sheet = Sheets("Sheet2") 'adjust name to result sheet
counter = 1


For x = 1 To 5 ' the sheets you should loop thru
    Set old_sheet = Sheets(x)
    end_row = old_sheet.Cells(old_sheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To end_row  'loop all rows
        If old_sheet.Cells(i, 5) > max_date Then 'if the date is larger, sve the date and the row
            max_date = old_sheet.Cells(i, 5)
            max_row = i
        End If

        if old_sheet.cells(i,j)<>"" then last_name = old_sheet.cells(i,j)

        If (old_sheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) <> "" and old_sheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) <> last_name) or i = end_row  Then
            For j = 1 To 4
                new_sheet(counter, j) = old_sheet(max_row, j) 'add the data to the new sheet
            Next j
            max_date = DateValue("01/01/1970") 'reset the date value
            counter = counter + 1 'new row to move the data to
        End If
    Next i
Next x
```

Comment: Thank you. It work quite well although I still have a problem : sometimes the last version of a document is not right above the next document. In my example, Line 4 could be empty, so I need to take Line 3 but the copy is made after the old_sheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) <> old_sheet.Cells(i, 1) test therefore not done in my case. How can I fix it ?

Comment: @Pierre-EtienneLeyder I have edited the code above to save a temp string.